# Consulta de registros duplicados MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos, donde se almacenan las facturas de la empresa, y necesito ver los registros duplicados (facturas que tienen la misma serie, número y tipo).
Por cada registro tengo un id autonumérico que las identifica.
Lo que quiero listar son todas las que estén duplicadas, no la cantidad.
Buscando en la web no he encontrado ninguna sentencia con la que pueda resolver ésto.

Por ej, de las que listo abajo, quiero ver solamente todas las que están duplicadas (A 809 y A 810):

```
**Tipo Serie Nro  Estado          Id**

111  A     807  Aceptada        9065
111  A     808  ErrorValidacion 7509
111  A     809  Aceptada        7519
111  A     809  ErrorValidacion 8287
111  A     809  ErrorValidacion 9066
111  A     809  ErrorValidacion 9123
111  A     810  ErrorValidacion 8288
111  A     810  ErrorValidacion 9067
111  A     810  ErrorValidacion 7574
111  A     810  Aceptada        7577
111  A     810  ErrorValidacion 9124
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La respuesta es esta (lo he probado):

```
    SELECT tipo,serie,nro
    FROM tabla
    WHERE nro
    IN (
    SELECT nro
    FROM tabla
    GROUP BY tipo,serie,nro
    HAVING count( nro ) >1
    )
    ORDER BY nro,tipo,serie
```

Comment: Gracias Adriana, si bien a veces aparece alguna que no está repetida (no se por qué), me sirve enormemente. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esta consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(0),Nro,Serie,Tipo from kk group by Nro,Serie,Tipo having count(0)>1
```

Comment: Por ahí anda, pero esa consulta me informa la cantidad que hay de repetidos, pero no me los muestra individualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar una consulta incluyendo "[HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) count(*) > 1" para mostrar únicamente los duplicados, el "[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)(id)" te permite agrupar separados por "," los id's que son repetidos (ten cuidado ya que tiene un límite de caracteres pero puede ser configurado), con el [GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)(serie) defines lo que quieres buscar que está duplicado.

```
SELECT group_concat(id), serie COUNT(*) Total
FROM invoices
GROUP BY serie
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

> Para aumentar el limite puedes intentar lo siguiente:
>   SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)[having](/questions/tagged/having)[concat](/questions/tagged/concat)[group](/questions/tagged/group)